# Cambiar los valores del eje x al eje y

Tags: python, matplotlib

estoy haciendo un trabajo y tenía que graficar un histograma, pero cuando lo grafico los valores que quiero que estén en el eje y lo están en el x (el 7471), quiero que la barra crezca hasta ese valor, no que la barra este ubicada en ese valor

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
y = [0, 7471]

ax = plt.subplot(231)
ax.set_title('Barcos')
ax.hist(y, ec="black", orientation='vertical')
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No debes usar `.hist()` para eso, pues este método calcula él mismo el histograma (es decir, va contando cuántos elementos hay de cada valor y te pinta las barras de la altura correspondiente al número de repeticiones de cada valor). En tu caso, ya que solo hay dos valores (0 y 7471) y cada uno de esos dos valores se repite una sola vez, pues te salen dos barras de altura 1 (1 repetición de cada valor).

En tu caso no quieres calcular el histograma pues entiendo que ya lo has calculado tú por otros métodos y sabes que hay 0 elementos del primer tipo y 7471 del segundo tipo. Por tanto basta que pintes un gráfico de barras, usando `ax.bar()`, así:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
y = [0, 7471]

ax = plt.subplot(231)
ax.set_title('Barcos')
ax.bar(["Tipo 0", "Tipo 1"], y)
plt.show()
```

Y el resultado es:

[image: Resultado]

Naturalmente puedes etiquetar las categorías del eje X como convenga a tu caso, en vez de "Tipo 1" y "Tipo 2"